# Pygame Automation snake refuses to crash wall?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, automation, pygame

I am creating Pygame script of traditional snake game which can run autonomously I.e. The snake should be aware of the surroundings (crash If hit the wall) and occupy the food

In order to do I just checking the next pixel position of the snake From every Direction NSWE
to determine snake trajectory by this Python `nextMove` function

I set the screen resolution to 600*400 i.e when the snake is approaching towards wall the value of coordinates becomes 0 to 600 (min to max height) and 0 to 400(min to max width)

```py
def nextMove(snake_head):

    x1=snake_head[0]
    y1=snake_head[1]
    next_left=x1-10
    next_right=x1+10
    next_top=y1-10
    next_down=y1+10
    print(next_left,next_right,next_top,next_down)

    if next_left<0:
        x1_change=10
        y1_change=0
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change
    if next_right>= dis_width:
        x1_change=-10
        y1_change=0
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change
    if next_top<0:
        x1_change=0
        y1_change=10
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change
    if next_down>=dis_height:
        x1_change=0
        y1_change=-10
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change
```

Snake head is a list which gives the value of x1,y1 coordinates
Although code has no error the snake still refuses and hit the wall

The full code

```py
import pygame
import time
import random
import math

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)

dis_width = 600
dis_height = 400

dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snake_block = 10
snake_speed = 15

font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)


def Your_score(score):
    value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score), True, yellow)
    dis.blit(value, [0, 0])



def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, black, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])

def nextMove(snake_head):

    x1=snake_head[0]
    y1=snake_head[1]
    next_left=x1-10
    next_right=x1+10
    next_top=y1-10
    next_down=y1+10
    print(next_left,next_right,next_top,next_down)

    if next_left<0:
        x1_change=10
        y1_change=0
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change
    if next_right>= dis_width:
        x1_change=-10
        y1_change=0
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change
    if next_top<0:
        x1_change=0
        y1_change=10
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change
    if next_down>=dis_height:
        x1_change=0
        y1_change=-10
        x1+=x1_change
        y1+=y1_change



def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    dis.blit(mesg, [dis_width / 6, dis_height / 3])


def gameLoop():
    game_over = False
    game_close = False

    x1 = dis_width / 2
    y1 = dis_height / 2

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    snake_List = []
    Length_of_snake = 1

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0

    while not game_over:

        while game_close == True:
            dis.fill(blue)
            message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", red)
            Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = snake_block
                    x1_change = 0




        if x1 >= dis_width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= dis_height or y1 < 0:
            game_close = True
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change

        dis.fill(blue)
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, green, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_List.append(snake_Head)
        print(snake_Head)
        #print(snake_List)
        if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_List[0]

        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True


        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)
        nextMove(snake_Head)
        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
        pygame.display.update()
        #determibe next move



        """    
        #calculating distance
        def Distance():
            x=snake_Head[0]
            y=snake_Head[1]
            dis_wleft=dis_width-x
            dis_wright=x-dis_wleft
            dis_wtop=dis_height-y
            dis_wdown=y-dis_wtop
            dis_food=math.sqrt(((foodx-x)**2)+((foody-y)**2))
            print(dis_wleft,dis_wright,dis_wtop,dis_wdown,dis_food)
        Distance()
        """


        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1

        clock.tick(snake_speed)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()


gameLoop()
```

Comment: Please stop using random upper case characters in your sentences. No idea what you're thinking you'll accomplish with that, but it makes reading your question really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x1_change`, `y1_change` are local variables in scope of `nextMove`. Variables with the same name exists in scope of `gameLoop`. This are different variables, they have just the same name. 
When you change `x1_change`, `y1_change` in `nextMove`, then do not change then identically named variables in `gameLoop`.

Add arguments to `nextMove` and return the changed values of `x1_change` and `y1_change`:

```py
def nextMove(snake_head, x_ch, y_ch):
    x1_change, y1_change = x_ch, y_ch

    # chang x1_change, y1_change
    # [...]

    return x1_change, y1_change
```

Pass `x1_change` and `y1_change` to and get the new values from `nextMove` in `gameLoop`:

```py
def gameLoop():

    # [...]

    while not game_over:

        # [...]

        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)

        x1_change, y1_change = nextMove(snake_Head, x1_change, y1_change)

        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
        pygame.display.update()
```

---

If the length of the snake grows, it will hit itself, when it changes the direction to the opposite.
I recommend to change the direction to the left or right instead:

```py
def nextMove(snake_head, x_ch, y_ch):

    x1_change, y1_change = x_ch, y_ch
    x1, y1 = snake_head
    next_x, next_y = x1 + x1_change, y1 + y1_change

    if next_x < 0 or next_x >= dis_width:
        x1_change = 0
        y1_change = 10 if y1 < dis_height // 2 else -10
    if next_y < 0 or next_y >= dis_height:
        x1_change = 10 if x1 < dis_width // 2 else -10
        y1_change = 0

    return x1_change, y1_change
```

Comment: Thanx For Help & Now Giving Error Of Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snext.py", line 188, in <module>
    gameLoop()
  File "snext.py", line 153, in gameLoop
    x1_change, y1_change = nextMove(snake_Head, x1_change, y1_change)
  File "snext.py", line 71, in nextMove
    return x1_change, y1_change
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y1_change' referenced before assignment

Comment: Again Checked Now The snake is Coming After Touching Wall:)

Comment: Thnx Now The Code runs Fine

Comment: There is Again A problem The Code Works Fine for Snake Size =2 after That The snake Is approaching Wall And Hitting Wall And Play Again Message Shown

Comment: No, you Can Check By Running Code

Comment: @Ddeadpool I've checked it, it hits itself. The relevant code is `for x in snake_List[:-1]:` `if x == snake_Head:` `game_close = True`. Comment is out and you'll see that the snake does not hit the wall.

Comment: @Ddeadpool Change the direction to the "left" or "right" instead. See the new section, which I've add to the answer right now.